# how can I save an excel as a PDF without adobe messing up the borders?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, adobe

I have been trying with no success to get my spreadsheets to print automatically. I have done quite a bit of research and a lot of people say that the drivers for printing to PDF vs exporting as PDF are different enough to affect the quality. The only thing that gets affected in my case is the borders. They are supposed to be thin borders around all cells but some get changed to medium after EXPORT but not after PRINT.

I can't get the PrintOut function to work because of issues with postscript and font. I have changed the settings for the Adobe printer to not rely only of system fonts but this didn't work in the end (I still get the post script error). I have found that some of my sheets will EXPORT with the correct thin borders if I first change all the borders to medium before I export while other sheets actually export with medium.

[image: exported with desired thin borders]

[image: exported with medium borders]

I don't know why they export differantly when the code is just a loop that does the same thing for each sheet. It basically selects the range and changes the borders to medium, exports the sheet to PDF, changes the borders back to thin and goes to the next sheet to repeat.

Out of six sheets the first three export in the desired way. Can anyone tell me why the first three are exporting with thin borders so I can get the rest to aswell. Or if you know a better way to get PrintOut to work or any other ideas that would be fancy!

Cheers,

Comment: My first suspicion here is scaling. If the paper size differs the expected, you can get this effect.

Comment: It might only be a workaround, but did you try "Hairline" also? `Border.Weight` can be `xlHairline, xlThin, xlMedium, xlThick`